# jQuery UI Datepicker disabling at AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm trying to disable an inline datepicker using the `.datepicker('disable')` method when the `onChangeMonthYear` callback function is fired.
This function makes an AJAX call (to fetch dates), and enables the datepicker back after success.

Unfortunately, the `.datepicker('disable')` never occurs ...

Apparently, after some deep digging with Firebug, the internal `_disableDatepicker` is called, but the class `hasDatePicker` is never found and thus the function returns early.

I have encapsulate the callback functions in a global object, but this does not seems to affect the behavior of my code.

`onChangeMonthYear` has a 3rd parameter, `inst`, that is supposed to refer to the datepicker element.
So I am supposed to access it through a `$(inst)` call.

You will find the complete code on http://jsbin.com/ahano4/6/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need to call the enable/disable by the actual element you're trying to affect?

```
$(inst).datepicker('disable');//generic and not referring to anything in the DOM
should be
$('#calendar').datepicker('disable');//referring to the datepicker object in the DIV with the ID 'calendar'
```

Comment: so what is the `inst` parameter good for? e.g. multiple datepickers? This seems to work but Chrome is not helping here because it is not disabling the datepicker!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your `getEventsForDate` function with some of the code removed.

```
this.getEventsForDate = function(year, month, inst) {
    ...
    $(inst).datepicker('disable');
    ...
};
```

And here is your code that runs after the DOM has been loaded

```
$(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    Calendar.getEventsForDate(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, {});
    ...
});
```

You are passing an empty object `{}` into the function as the third parameter and then calling the `.datepicker()` function on it. This clearly will not do anything useful.

Comment: Ok I've changed it using FatherStorm answers.
This was only to initiate the values for the current month.